# What is wrong with my network configuration?

Tags: networking, server, static-ip

This is what I have in `/etc/network/interfaces`

```
auto eth0 
iface eth0 inet static
 address 192.168.1.34
 netmask 255.255.255.0
 network 192.168.0.0
 broadcast 192.168.1.255
 gateway 192.168.1.254
```

when I type `/etc/init.d/networking` restart it says

```
Runnig etc/init.d/networking restart is deprecated because it may not enable again some    interfaces
Reconfiguring network interfaces...
RTNETLINK answers: No such process
```

then I do an `ifconfig` to see what changed and nothing changes, sometimes when I restart the network more than once and check the `ifconfig` I see that It erases everything but by the next restart everything is back to normal again (without the changes that I want).

the bcast before the change is: `192.168.1.255`
and the subnet mask is `/24`
I did not change those.

Comment: see here: Running http://codeghar.wordpress.com/2011/07/18/debian-running-etcinit-dnetworking-restart-is-deprecated-because-it-may-not-enable-again-some-interfaces/. I didn't try it but I hope it helps.

Comment: Your network can be network 192.168.0.0 must be 192.168.1.0. Mask is 255.255.255.0

Comment: @2707974 It works, why does it have to be that network. I though 192.168.0.0 covered all networks "192.168.254.254"

Comment: when I try to do apt-get update it gives me errors

Comment: @user3368897 Network mask tell you what is on your pc lan. I your case from 192.168.1.1 till 192.168.1.254, all other packets will be send via gateway aka 192.168.1.254. `network` is the network base address and in your case is 192.168.1.0. You do not "cover" more network, you only make mistake.